# Login Form error

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I am creating a login form. Where if the Login-id and password matches with the values stored in Register table it retrieves all values from Register table and the result stores in the SqlDataReader object .So, now I want to access accountid and type from this table.How can we do it?

To understand what I am trying to say please have a look on the following code-

--------------------Login.aspx.cs---------------------------------------------------------------

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ROCConStr"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(conStr);
scon.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select* from Register where email= @login_id and pwd=@password", scon);
SqlParameter Para;
Para = cmd.Parameters.Add("@login_id", SqlDbType.Char);
Para.Value = email.Text;
Para = cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.Char);
Para.Value = pwd.Text;
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if(reader.HasRows)
{if (reader["account_type"]=="admin") /* error - Please see the bottom for more details.*/
Response.Redirect("http://localhost:1187/roc/WelcomeAdmin.aspx");
else
Response.Redirect("http://localhost:1187/roc/WelcomeUser.aspx");}
else
{ Label1.Text = "UserID or password is incorrect."; }
reader.Close();
scon.Close();
}

==================================================

<br>About the erro:- reader["account_type"]=="admin"
```

I dont know how to retrieve the value of a single column.So, I just typed to show what I want to do. I tested this code I got the error - "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present."

Comment: Don't write `SELECT *` unless you really want every single column.

Comment: You should dispose your objects in `using` statements.

Comment: you can redirect to "~/WelcomeUser.aspx" instead of hardcoding the URL. Just a suggestion

Comment: the selection of the @password in the DB is not a secure plan. Please don't select passwords FROM the DB, only send password TO the database but NEVER return them again. Passwords should (almost) never leave the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `reader.Read()` to move to the first row.

<strike>Alternatively, change your query to select only the column you want, then call `ExecuteScalar` to return that value directly (or `null` if there were no rows) without using a DataReader at all.</strike>
(you can't do this, since you want more than one column)

Comment: @caspar : Thanks for edit. <br>@Slaks: I believe from now i will do that for passwords.

Answer (score 1):

You've only checked to see if you 'HasRows'; but you still need to advance the Reader.  `reader.Read()`

That should fix your problem.  You might want to also consider incorporating 'using' statements to limit the scope of your objects and modifying your URLs to use relative paths instead of absolute.  That way, if you deploy to a new environment or move servers you don't have to remove the hard-coded URL.